# Google Chrome tabs become unusably small when I have too many tabs. How to fix?

Tags: google-chrome

So firstly, forgive me if this is the wrong place to post this. I really want to switch to Chrome as I have been having issues with FF lately, but there is primarily ONE thing that is holding me back from giving Chrome an honest shot. The tabs.

It appears that Google has gone out of its way to make them as unusable as possible. And it has worked! The tabs become unusably small when you have too many. Let me demonstrate via the following image:
[image: A comparative screenshot of Firefox and Chrome's tab bar]

The top screenshot corresponds to Firefox and the bottom to Chrome. Oddly, Chrome wants to display ALL tabs in one glance, and consequently makes the tabs SO small that I don't know what is what. I typically have 30+ tabs open in one session, so this image is representative of a typical session for me.

I have recently learned that there is this hidden feature called "Stacked Tabs" in Chrome that is the perfect fix. Turns out that the devs recently decided to axe this feature on the PC for the sake of easier maintenance. I just don't understand how they think what they have is good. The stacked tabs feature is available on mobile versions of Chrome and it works well.

Coming to the question: Can I fix the behavior of Chrome's tabs somehow to make it more like Firefox? Is there an addon, is there a way to tinker with internal settings, may be recompile something to reinstate the feature. ANYTHING?

Or, do you suggest a better browser instead, preferably something that has the nice addons that I have come to love in FF and Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has many extensions for customization. Try this one.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp?hl=en

or this one

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-manager/coonecdghnepgiblpccbbihiahajndda?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have looked into these extensions earlier and while not the perfect solution, it is something. I only wish Google put a tad more thought into making the browser more capable of working with many tabs. It seems like an odd and very important thing to ignore!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found numerous browser extensions that you can use to decrease the number of tabs open. My 3 favorites :

- **one tab**: it's a good one, because very customizable but not super ergonomic to my opinion (lots of clicks, and swiss knife of options):

-> chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en

-> firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/onetab/

- **the great suspender**: it saves your RAM rather than fighting visual pollution, but it's quite efficient. It's powerful if not only you have trouble with tabs, but tabs also slows your computer down.

-> chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg

-> firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ff-tab-suspender/

- **tabby:** it automatically and silently removes unnecessary  tabs so that you always have a clean view on the browser. "Focus mode" is a bit too harsh for me and I was not used to no complex settings, but the "relax mode" (target to 12 tabs) is smooth and efficient

-> chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabby/bloclegocjpjjaandifppeocigahekjg/

-> firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/android/addon/tabby_tabs/